# Is it possible to use virtual paths / subfolders registering scripts in Orchard Themes?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to build a new Orchard theme, and to keep things structures I'd like to put script includes in separate folders (this particular script include needs quite a bit of files so to put all of them in the root of the scripts folder doesn't seem so great).

Basicly I can't wrap my head around this:

```
Script.Require("~/ThemesFolderEtc/Scripts/libs/shadowbox/shadowbox.js");
```

it seems only possible to do something like this:

```
Script.Require("shadowbox.js");
```

Does anyone have any pointers on what virtual path to use, and if it's supported to use virtual paths?

Comment: Although not the most clean solution I fixed it by simply including the javascript references in the Document.cshtml template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Script.Require is key/value dictionary of registered scripts.  Try Script.Include("path").  This is what I do with my css file.  I point it to a file on in public dropbox folder which makes changing the css super easy and no ftp!

Comment: Thanks that worked :) I'm new to using Orchard, so this wasn't quite obvious to me, and I couldn't' really find any reference material on this somewhere else.